# how to done bean validation

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

this is my code sample for bean validation.but case is in form filed the error message is not show

```
//controller class
        @RequestMapping(value= "/offer.create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String doActions(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("offers") Offer offer, BindingResult result,
                @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map,
                HttpServletRequest request){
            
        //  
            
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                /*map.put("offers", offerservice.getAlloffers());
                map.put("Offer", new Offer());
                map.put("SeasonTypes", new SeasonTypes());
                map.put("timeBased", new TimeBased());
                map.put("seasons", offerservice.getAllSeasons());*/
                System.out.println("inside the error section!!");
    //          System.out.println(merchantService.getAllMerchant().size());
                System.out.println("The error "+result);
                
                return "create-offer";
                
                
                
            }
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is the jsp form

```
<div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <div class="panel panel-default red box">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
                            
                                <h4 class="panel-title">Single Image</h4>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                        
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Upload or drag and drop image of your choice</p>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;width:100%;">
                                                            <form action="upload.image1" class="dropzone dropzone-mini" style="width:145px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                            
                                            <form:form action="offer.create" method="POST" commandName="Offer" id="formID" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                                            
                                                     <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Merchant Name</label>
                                                     <form:input path="offerHeading" class="form-control normtxtin" />
                                                     <form:errors path="offers.*" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Heading</label>
                                                     <form:input path="offerSubheading" class="form-control normtxtin" />
                                                     <form:errors path="offers.*" cssClass="text-warning"></form:errors>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Description</label>
                                                     <form:textarea path="offerDescription" rows="5" cols="30" class="form-control normtxtin"/>
                                                  </div>
                                                  
                                                   <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Issue Date</label>
                                                   <form:input path="issueDateTime" type="date"  class="form-control normtxtin" placeholder="Select date"/>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Expiration Date</label>
                                                   <form:input path="expiryDate" type="date" class="form-control normtxtin"  placeholder="Select date"/>
                                                  </div>
 
                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Offer Discount</label>
                                                    <form:input path="offerDiscount" class="form-control normtxtin" placeholder="offer Discount for the Entire offer"/>
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Allocated points </label>
                                                    <form:input path="offerPrice" class="form-control normtxtin" />
                                                  </div>
                                                  
                                                   <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Offer Price</label>
                                                    <form:input path="pointsAllocated" class="form-control normtxtin" />
                                                  </div>
                                                  
                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">offer Claim Limit</label>
                                                    <form:input path="offerClaimLimit" class="form-control normtxtin" />
                                                  </div>

                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Available Branches</label>
                                                   
                                                    <form:input path="offerAvailableBranches" class="form-control normtxtin" placeholder="Add branches seperated by a ',' Ex: galle, colombo, Kandy" />
                                                  </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;font-size:16px;padding:10px;" name="action" value="Add">Create Offer</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                 </form:form>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

this is the model class

```
public class Offer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long offerid;
    private Merchant merchant;
    private MerchantUser merchantUserByAddedByRef;
    private MerchantUser merchantUserByLastModifiedByRef;
    private String issueDateTime;
    private BigDecimal pointsAllocated;
    private String expiryDate;
    private String offerHeading;
    @NotEmpty
    private String offerSubheading;
    @NotEmpty
    private String offerDescription;
    private String offerFilterTypes;
    private String videoUrl;
```

this is the message.property file

```
NotEmpty.Offer.offerSubheading = Heading field can't be Empty!
NotEmpty.Offer.offerDescription = Heading field can't be Empty!
```

in here in jsp page, after clicking button will appear relevant form.when after doing validation if their has some error it redirect to the jsp page then shouldn't have that form here.because of that form will appear only after button click .so that error msg can not shown

following images are that .jsp view [.jsp page view before press single image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJHOX.png)  [after click that single image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBO5.png)

Comment: Sorry -- is there a question somewhere in here?

Comment: yes it is. I need to redirect form .      but here not redirect that form after with validation error . above link show the jsp page I need to redirect image that shown in 2nd link [2] not [1]               [1]jsp page view before press single image button [2]after click that single image button

Answer (score 0):

finally i did my work 
the problem was  @ModelAttribute ("offers") ---> offers and  commandName="Offer"  are not match each other 
:)